# Using split in python to iterate through columns

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-2.x

I am trying to use split in python to iterate through columns but when trying to access columns I get an error that a particular list index is out of range.

This is what my file looks like:

```
chr1    15585711    .   A   T   45.7081 .   AB=0;ABP=0;AC=2;AF=1;AN=2;AO=3;CIGAR=1X;DP=3;DPB=3;DPRA=0;EPP=9.52472;EPPR=0;GTI=0;LEN=1;MEANALT=1;MQM=60;MQMR=0;        NS=1;NUMALT=1;ODDS=8.76405;PAIRED=0;PAIREDR=0;PAO=0;PQA=0;PQR=0;PRO=0;QA=78;QR=0;RO=0;RPP=9.52472;RPPR=0;RUN=1;SAF=0;SAP=9.52472;SAR=3;SRF=0;SRP=0;SRR=0;            TYPE=snp  GT:DP:RO:QR:AO:QA:GL    1/1:3:0:0:3:78:-7.28,-0.90309,0
```

And here is my code:

```
target = open('file', 'r')

for line in target:
    line = line.split('\t')
    print line[1]
```

When I print line it looks like a list to me, and `line[0]` does access `chr1` which is the first column. But then when I try to access the other columns i cannot.

Comment: Are you sure its TAB separated ('\t')? It does not seem like that. Try `line.split()` to split on every whitespace

Comment: `line[0] does access chr1` <- you're asking for `line[1]` in your code, though

Comment: What do you get with `print line.split('\t')`

Comment: It should be tab separated. And @Lafexlos I get the following: `['chr1', '15585711', '.', 'A', 'T', '45.7081', '.', 'AB=0;ABP=0;AC=2;AF=1;AN=2;AO=3;CIGAR=1X;DP=3;DPB=3;DPRA=0;EPP=9.52472;EPPR=0;GTI=0;LEN=1;MEANALT=1;MQM=60;MQMR=0;NS=1;NUMALT=1;ODDS=8.76405;PAIRED=0;PAIREDR=0;PAO=0;PQA=0;PQR=0;PRO=0;QA=78;QR=0;RO=0;RPP=9.52472;RPPR=0;RUN=1;SAF=0;SAP=9.52472;SAR=3;SRF=0;SRP=0;SRR=0;TYPE=snp', 'GT:DP:RO:QR:AO:QA:GL', '1/1:3:0:0:3:78:-7.28,-0.90309,0\n']`

Comment: You are reusing the variable line and changing it. It probably works the first time but the next time through you've already split it on tab... only one entry in that case.

Comment: Then just use another variable name to assign. Anything but `line` or work with split's result directly like `line.split('\t')[1]`.

Comment: The line you pasted here is not tab separated. You might want to try using a regexp though line.split(r'\s+')

Comment: @MadWombat that does not appear to split the line. It just puts the entire line as the first item in the list.

Comment: @GáborErdős I tried this and sill accessing anything past `line.split()[0]` is out of range.

Comment: I missed your previous comment. It looks like it does split the line into fields for you, so print line[1] should give you '15585711'. Do you get an error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just created a text file with data you provided and was able to split it without any problem. I would suggest to use `with open` it'll close your file for you when you're done:

```
with open('test', 'rb') as target:
    for line in target:
        print line.split()[1]
```

Output:

```
15585711
```

Answer (score 1):

The source is not using tabs. Just use:

```
line = line.split()
```

Comment: when I try this I still get the same error. However if I just paste the text into a variable and then split I do not get an error.